# article link does't work in joomla 3.1

Tags: joomla, hyperlink, article

down vote

i have problem with my article link on joomla 3.1 i'm using custom html module for the pic of link. i made 2 custom html. one in "home" and another one at another page. both of them using same link code ( index.php?option=com_content&view=article&layout=edit&id=id_article). problem, at "home" link doesn't work (still load "home" page, and in address bar mysite.com/index.php?option=com_content&Itemid=435&id=271&lang=en&layout=edit&view=article) and on other pages, the link work properly ( at address bar mysite.com/index.php?option=com_content&Itemid=494&id=271&lang=en&layout=edit&view=article)

note both of permalink using same code and same article id( index.php?option=com_content&view=article&layout=edit&id=id_article)

thank you for attention and for help...

Comment: Cant you make these links more friendly? In 2.5 I was making hidden menu items for each article. Did they change this in 3.1? I think if you sort your URLs it would be easier to do whatever you want.

Comment: using hidden menu can't solve my problem. by the way thank you for your resnpon. any other solution.?

Comment: using sh404sef and jce can't solve to...